# Gulp.watch refreshes my browser one time, but then not again

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am having trouble setting up my browser to watch for changes in my html and css files and refresh the browser. Currently, it only works once.

I am a total js noob so I apologize since it looks like this has been answered already, but I was unable to apply the fixes to my situation.

Here is my gulpfile.js

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('browserSync',function(){
    browserSync.init(null,{
        open : false,
        server : {
            baseDir : 'site',
            
            index : "index.html"
        }
     });
     console.log("finshed browser ");
});

gulp.task('watch', gulp.parallel('browserSync', function() {
 gulp.watch('site/index.html', browserSync.reload); 
 gulp.watch('site/css/main.css', browserSync.reload); 
}))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try gulp.task('watch', gulp.parallel('browserSync', function(done) {
 gulp.watch('site/index.html', browserSync.reload); 
 gulp.watch('site/css/main.css', browserSync.reload); done(); 
}))  You should also do the same for the 'browserSync' task.

Comment: Got it working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code thatI ended up going with was

```html
gulp.task('watch', gulp.parallel('browserSync', function() {
 gulp.watch('site/index.html', function (done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
  }); 
 gulp.watch('site/css/main.css', function (done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
  });
```

It's working now.